# A word that describes all of my close friends

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes all of my close friends whom I go out with and we are best friends? Is "company" appropriate for this usage?
Sorry if it is a dumb question.

Comment: How about my "circle of friends", my "friendship circle" or perhaps just "my circle"? You can also have a "professional circle", a "social circle" or a "sports-club circle" - or perhaps "family circle". I think "circle" works rather better than "company".

Comment: WS2 is absolutely right. But note that you can keep company with some people, i.e. associate with them. That's why the proverb "A man is known by the company he keeps" is common.

Comment: The question lists three characterstics of the people that the term that is sought needs to cover: (1) their being close friends, (2) one’s going out with them, (3) their being best friends. Are these supposed to be three *distinct* characteristics? Is each of the people covered by the term supposed to exhibit all three?

Comment: I would say "inner circle"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My wife, a linguist, and her close friends, also linguists, tend to refer to their core group as a "[cohort](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cohort)." Seems like an expert opinion to me. Consider, however, that they have paid close attention to the definition. They all share the same statistical factor of being linguists.

Although the term "[clique](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clique)" engenders thoughts of high-school "popular" kids, any closely knit or exclusively qualified group of people applies. In addition, you could consider its synonyms:

> Synonyms
>   body, bunch, circle, clan, community, coterie, coven, crowd, fold, gang, lot, network, pack, ring, set
>   [(from Merriam Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clique)

or

> cabal,
>   clan,
>   coterie,
>   faction,
>   gang,
>   mob,
>   posse,
>   bunch,
>   camarilla
>   star
>   camp,
>   circle,
>   club,
>   crew,
>   crowd,
>   crush,
>   insiders,
>   lobby,
>   Mafia,
>   organization,
>   outfit,
>   pack,
>   ring,
>   set,
>   society,
>   in-group
>   [(from Thesaurus.com)](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/clique)

Answer (score 1):

a **coterie**. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/coterie)

A small, often select group of persons who associate with one another frequently

Answer (score 0):

**Fellowship**

> A friendly relationship marked by ready communication and mutual
> understanding

Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/fellowship)